# How do I mark a class as a singleton in UML?

Tags: singleton, uml

I have an UML diagram on which I want to mark some classes as singletons (because they are). How do I do that? Do I invent a new stereotype or do I just add a comment or are there some existing means to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Craig Larman's "Applying UML and Patterns" book (3rd edition) gives the following notation for a sequence diagram:

[image]

Note that it implies that before calling `doA` the `:Register` object manages to get access to the singleton via the standard way, e.g., `getInstance()`. This makes the diagram more agile.

For a class diagram:

[image]

Comment: The notation with the 1 in the upper right corner of a class is not valid in UML version 2.5.

Answer (score 16):

"What will most clearly represent the concept to your reader."

There is a reasonable example of the basic appearance over on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Singleton_UML_class_diagram.svg).  It shows a private constructor and a public `getInstance()` method that returns an object of type `Singleton`.  I'd also find a stereotype to be a perfectly reasonable way to make it explicit without requiring your reader to parse the details of the class object.

Comment: I would definitely prefer the stereotype. FWIW

Answer (score 2):

To specify that a class is a singleton, you can write a constraint in between braces: { number of instances = 1 }. This constraint should be put in a constraints compartment in the class rectangle.

[image: classdiagram]

The UML 2.5 specification, §7.6.4 defines the notation for constraints in general and §9.2.4 specifies how to show the constraints of a classifier:

> If a Classifier owns Constraints, a conforming tool may implement a compartment to show the owned Constraints listed
>   within a separate compartment of the owning Classifier’s rectangle. The name of this optional compartment is
>   “constraints.”

Alternatively, you could invent your own stereotype ≪singleton≫.