# UML Unique Entity

Tags: model, uml, entity

How can I visualize that one entity is unique?

Example:
There are unlimited numbers of users. Every user has a name, location and age.
There is just one banking account, where users may own part of the money.

So, one user can have one banking account (which is always the same one) while the banking account can have unlimited users.

How can I show that it is always the same (unique) banking account and not a new one for every user (which UML normally signals)?

Comment: I don't know in which world you live, but I have ONE bank account where MY money is held and it's not a share of a money pile that sums up at the bank.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I mark a class as a singleton in UML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8386785/how-do-i-mark-a-class-as-a-singleton-in-uml)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a concept that represents a particular user’s percentage share of this single account. That would then be associated with the single account.

One way to express that all shares refer to the same account is to make the property relating them to the account a “class static”.

Another perhaps more realistic and flexible way to model this is with an OCL constraint that says all shares in an account must equal 100%. That way you can have multiple accounts, each having shares. A share would be owned by one person, but a person could own many shares in many accounts.