# How to represent in UML that subclasses of an abstract class should be singleton

Tags: uml

Suppose an abstract class X and its subclasses Y and Z. How do I represent in UML class diagrams that Y and Z should be singletons. Is it possible to represent that all X subclasses must be singletons?

Comment: Thinking over that makes me wonder what's the rationale for forcing subclasses to be Singletons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To specify that all subclasses of X are singletons, you can write a constraint in between braces: { every subclass of X is a singleton }. This constraint should be put in a constraints compartment in the class rectangle.

[image: classdiagram]

The UML 2.5 specification, §7.6.4 defines the notation for constraints in general and §9.2.4 specifies how to show the constraints of a classifier:

> If a Classifier owns Constraints, a conforming tool may implement a compartment to show the owned Constraints listed
>   within a separate compartment of the owning Classifier’s rectangle. The name of this optional compartment is
>   “constraints.”

Alternatively, you could give a singleton indication on each and every subclass of X. From your wording, I assume that that is not what you want. Anyway, the latest version of UML (2.5.1) does not have a standard way to indicate that a class is a singleton. Some people indicate it by writing 1 in the top right corner of the rectangle. However, that is not valid UML. You may use that for parts, but not for classes. Instead, you could invent your own stereotype ≪singleton≫.

[There is another StackOverflow question about this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8386785/how-do-i-mark-a-class-as-a-singleton-in-uml).

Comment: @JimL. , qwerty_so  : You are right, I was wrong. I'll modify my answer.

Comment: If you'd remove the link to the other answer I'd upvote since that linked one is just outdated.

Answer (score 0):

§11.4.4 of the UML 2.5 spec says:

> A usage dependency may relate an InstanceSpecification to a
>   constructor for a Class, describing the single value returned by the
>   constructor Operation. The Operation is the client, the created
>   instance the supplier.

If you create a GeneralizationSet that has the meta-property `isComplete=true` (to say that all possible subclasses are accounted for), and you connect one InstanceSpecification to each constructor by a usage dependency, the model means that every class is a singleton.

Comment: Please elaborate. What is the answer to the question "Is it possible to represent in a class diagram that all X subclasses must be singletons?" yes or no? If it is yes, how do you represent an InstanceSpecification that ensures that constraint in a class diagram?

Comment: Okay, I elaborated.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another possibility: you can adorn the class with a `<<singleton>>` stereotype. I always used it that way and the coder knows how to handle that. It's no UML standard, but see the last sentence.

Comment: What do you mean by 'see the last sentence' ?

Comment: Well, that one before: _the coder knows how to handle that_